# In Grails how do I capture multiple selected items in g:select?

Tags: grails, view, layout

I have a Contact Domain class that can be associated with multiple Organizations, which are also domain classes. I want to use a multiple selection box to allow the user to select the organizations that are associated with the current contact. The selection box is populated with the available organizations. How do I assign the selected items to the organizations list in my Contact class?

```
 <g:select name="organizations.id"  
           multiple="multiple" 
           optionKey="id" 
           from="${com.ur.Organization.list()}" 
           value="${contact?.organizations}" />
```

The above is what I am currently trying, and while it does populate the selection with organizations it doesn't seem to put the selected items in my organizations field.

Thanks for any advice.

Edit:
Incorporated comments from krsjunk and omarello.

Here's an abbreviated version of the domain classes.

```
class Contact{
    static searchable = true
    static mapping = {
        sort "lastName"
    }
    String firstName
    String lastName
    .  
    .
    .
    static belongsTo = [organizations:Organization, projects:Project]
}

class Organization {
    static searchable = true
    static mapping = {
        sort "name"
    }
    String name
    static hasMany = [contacts:Contact]
}
```

Comment: Try changing your name to name="organizations.id"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well just change the name to

```
<g:select name="organizations"  multiple="multiple" 
          optionKey="id" 
          from="${com.ur.Organization.list()}" 
          value="${contact?.organizations}" />
```

Should work fine, just tried it.

Note my domain definitions look like this, (just in case you have something different

```
class Contact {

    static constraints = {
    }

    static hasMany = [organizations:Organization]

    String name
}


class Organization {

    static constraints = {
    }

    static hasMany = [contacts:Contact]
    static belongsTo = [Contact]

    String name
}
```

Comment: Works great for a single selection, but when I select more than one items I get an exception because the select is returning a list of strings representing the id instead of a list of objects.

Comment: Hmm, do you have an almost similar domain def. as the above. I just tried the sample i created with multiple selection and it seems to work fine, saving and retrieving. What is the exception you get?

Comment: Ah, my hasMany mapping is from Organizations to Contacts. Contacts "belong to" organizations. That seems to be the problem. I'll update the question to better illustrate. Here's the exception anyway.                executing action [save] of controller [com.ur.ContactController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.ur.Organization.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [2, 3] Possible solutions: get(java.lang.Object), getId(), getAt(java.lang.String), getAll(), ident(), getLog()
Servlet: grails

Answer (score 1):

one problem is that `value="contact?.organizations"` should be `value="${contact?.organizations}"` — not sure if that is the whole problem or not.  (also, the attribute `multiple=".."` is not necessary if value is a collection)

You may also need `name="contact.organizations"` to be `name="contact.organizations.id"` and another attribute `optionKey="id"`

Comment: Made the changes but no luck.  I did try removing the mulitple, but that made the selection a single line selection so I added it back.

Comment: sorry, without setting up an example it is difficult to see all the pieces… did you try value="${contact?.organizations?.id}" (which should provide a collection of IDs assuming organizations is a list from a hasMany relationship)

Comment: You are correct, organizations is a list from a hasMany relationship. I tried using ${contact?.organizations?.id} but still nothing is saved to the list. Could my "from" attribute be returning the "toString" representation of Organization, which would not map to the Organization list?

Answer (score 0):

In your newly edit domain example you don't have a one-to-many relationship between contact and organization.  You have a one-to-many from organization to contact.

So

```
value="${contact?.organizations}"
```

will always be a single item, never a list.

Trying to select/assign multiple organization to a contact will never be valid.

Comment: I see your point. How would I go about updating the list of organizations so that they contain a reference to the contact using the organizations selected in the list?

Comment: Yep what krsjunk mentioned is correct, you define contact to belong to an organization, i.e. only one. You need to define a has many in order to achieve what you want. Since a contact can have multiple organizations associated (according to your initial req.)

Comment: If you want multiple organizations associated to a given contact you'll have to change your domain model to look more like the one omarello presented in his answer.

Comment: I think there may be a way to make this happen without changing my domain model, but it will take custom taglibs & possibly controller code.  I'll report back when/if I get it working.